# Set text to Input from javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have a simple html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=0;" />
<title>My HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>MyHTML</h1>
<p id="mytext">Hello!</p>
<input type="button" id="but" value="Say hello"
    onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />
<input type="button" value="Open Dialog" onClick="openAndroidDialog()" />
<input type="text" class="textfield" name="email" value="" />
<script language="javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        AndroidFunction.showToast(toast);
    }

    function openAndroidDialog() {
        AndroidFunction.openAndroidDialog();
    }

    function callFromActivity(msg) {
        document.getElementById("mytext").innerHTML = msg;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I want set text to input field "email" and do this:
`myBrowser.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementByName(\"email\").value=\"eeee\"");`

but in doesnt work! Please help
 me, whats a problem?

p.s sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried using `document.getElementsByName(\"email\")[0].value`